# Defining the number of a class of functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have a set A and I want to consider all the functions $f:x \rightarrow A$ for $x \in A$. How do I define the cardinality of the set of such functions?

I can't get my head around the cardinal arithmetic on this; even a hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The notation $f:X\to A$ implies $X$ is a set (the domain of $f$), but you seem to imply otherwise?

Comment: @gt6989b I didn't mean to imply otherwise. I can edit it to be lowercase if that would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a given $x \in A$, the number of such functions is $|A|^{|x|}$. If you want the number of such functions for any $x$, simply sum $|A|^{|x|}$ over $x \in A$. Without knowing more about $A$ we cannot simplify further.

Comment: To sum $|A|^{|x|}$ over $x \in A$, would that be the cardinality of $\bigcup_{x \in A}  |A|^{|x|}$?

Comment: Sure, since for distinct $x$, you necessarily get distinct functions (it’s really a disjoint union).